# r - Wrap function only showing result of last function

Tags: r, wrap-function

I'm attempting to write my first wrap function, showing the mean, variance, stdev, and summary for a vector in r

```
des_function = function(y)
  {
  mean(y); 
  var(y);
  sd(y);
  summary(y);
  }
des_function(even)
```

but it's only showing the results of the summary function:

```
des_function(even)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    2.0   251.5   501.0   501.0   750.5  1000.0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this slight change:

```
#Function
des_function = function(y)
{
  list(
  mean(y), 
  var(y),
  sd(y),
  summary(y)
  )
}
#Apply
des_function(even)
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks Duck. I'll read into the list() function to understand it better!

Comment: @WilliamSilvia Amazing! If you think this answer was useful, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Comment: Will do! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

We could create a `tibble` and return the tibble

```
library(tibble)
des_function <- function(y) {
        tibble(Mean = mean(y), Var = var(y), SD = sd(y), Summary = list(summary(y)))
 }
```